# ELISP: Function to prompt user for number and ask user for that number of strings and insert then into list

Tags: function, emacs, elisp, user-input

I'd like to create an ELISP function that will prompt a user for a number, n, then continually prompt the user n times for strings. Ideally, I'd like all these string put into a list. Here's what I have so far. Obviously, what I have doesn't work, but it might help clarify the type of thing I want to do.

```
(defun prompt-user-n-times (n)
  "Prompt user n time for strings and append strings to list"
  (interactive "nHow many strings: ")

  (while (> n 0)
    (append newlist (interactive "sGive me input: "))
    (setq n (- n 1))
))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

just define a binding for your new list:

```
(defun prompt-user-n-times (n)
  "Prompt user n time for strings and append strings to list"
  (interactive "nHow many strings: ")

  (let ((newlist ()))
    (while (> n 0)
      (setq newlist (append newlist (list (read-string "Give me input: "))))
      (setq n (- n 1)))
    newlist))
```

Several remark: interactive is only at beginning of a `defun`, in the
function, one use other prompt function, like the simple
`read-string`. `append` ask for two list, so the string returned
by `read-string` should be put into a list by the `list` function

Comment: Note that `append` is somewhat of an antipattern because it will traverses the list every time. The standard idiom is: `(let ((newlist nil)) (dotimes (i n) (push (read-from-minibuffer ...) newlist)) (nreverse newlist))`. Or, if you're not averse to `loop`: `(loop repeat n collect (read-from-minibuffer ...))`